# How to make paypal to paypal payment api integration in windows application c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, paypal, windows

I want to integrate paypal to paypal payment(No Credit card) in my c# windows application.
Anybody have solution?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is this [PayPal .NET SDK NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PayPal/). This package is developed by PayPal itself and works well for both one time payments and subscriptions. We use it in our projects and although some minor parts are hard to understand, this is not a fault in the package itself, but of the PayPal's REST API.

On the [project site on GitHub](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK), you can find tutorials on how to start using the package, how to setup development versions etc. Simply, all you need.

Finally, you will need to understand [PayPal REST API itself](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/).